# Slowly animate button on fade with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have an input button that has an image from css. The image from the css changes its background-position when the input button is hovered or clicked on.

For instance.

```
input { height: 50px; width: 100px; background-position: 0 0; }
input:hover { background-position: 0 -60px; }
input:active { background-position: 0 -120px; }
```

How can i use jQuery to make the transition a slow-smooth fade, instead of an automatic change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using CSS, bind jQuery's `fadeTo()` to the click/hover events as necessary.

You can also take a look at the related functions, fadeIn(), fadeOut(), and fadeToggle().

```
$('input').hover( function(){ 
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.75);
},
function(){ 
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Comment: For some reason the background position just isnt working, and this isnt exactly what i need, but it will do until i figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Just an example:

```
$('#myElement')
    .css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} )
    .mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(0 -150px)"}, 
            {duration:200})
        })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 
            {duration:200})
        })
```

EDIT:

Of course you have to add the onClick-event as well.

Comment: I tried so many different variation of using animate.. Other styles work such as height, but when i try backgroundPosition it dosnt work...

Comment: Ok, maybe my answer was not thought through enough - it might be that the background position does not work originally (I can't test right now). Did you already tried the following plugin (as ShankarSangoli pointed out already)?
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect

Comment: I didnt, ill try it now. but is it possible its not working since im using a class and and input instead of an id?

Comment: Usually the selector should not change anything (both an id or a class should be handled the same way.. as long as your selector is implemented correctly). But what does that mean: "since im using a class **and** input"?

Comment: I have the 'changing' background image on a class, and also on an input[type="submit"]. The plugin does work, but maybe i dont have the proper styles associated. I have only the background position specified and on hover the background image scrolls. I want the background image to fade from one to the next...

Comment: Why you use the event/animation on two selectors that represents the same element? Maybe they work contrarily.
Anyway, the first thing I would try to do is to use ie firebug or the chrome  developer tools to validate your CSS first - without any javascript. Maybe there's already a mistake.
If not, I would try to minimize your code as much as possible to figure out if the problem does not occure in any other layer.
Is it possible that you post a complete example of your code, so that it's more easy to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgImageTransition

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/